# Merge and update dataframes based on a subset of their columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wonder whether there is the fastest code to replace the two for loops, assuming the df size is very large. In my real case, each dataframe is 200 rows and 25 columns.

```
data_df1 = np.array([['Name','Unit','Attribute','Date'],['a','A',1,2014],['b','B',2,2015],['c','C',3,2016],\
                 ['d','D',4,2017],['e','E',5,2018]])
data_df2 = np.array([['Name','Unit','Date'],['a','F',2019],['b','G',2020],['e','H',2021],\
                 ['f','I',2022]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_df1)
print('df1:')
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_df2)
print('df2:')
print(df2)
row_df1 = [1,2,5]
col_df1 = [1,3]
row_df2 = [1,2,3]
col_df2 = [1,2]
for i in range(0,len(row_df1)):
    for j in range(0, len(col_df1)):
        df1.set_value(row_df1[i],col_df1[j], df2.loc[row_df2[i],col_df2[j]])
print('df1 after operation:')
print(df1)
```

Expected output:

```
df1:
      0     1          2     3
0  Name  Unit  Attribute  Date
1     a     A          1  2014
2     b     B          2  2015
3     c     C          3  2016
4     d     D          4  2017
5     e     E          5  2018
df2:
      0     1     2
0  Name  Unit  Date
1     a     F  2019
2     b     G  2020
3     e     H  2021
4     f     I  2022
df1 after operation:
      0     1          2     3
0  Name  Unit  Attribute  Date
1     a     F          1  2019
2     b     G          2  2020
3     c     C          3  2016
4     d     D          4  2017
5     e     H          5  2021
```

I have tried:

```
df1.loc[[1,2,5],[1,3]] = df2.loc[[1,2,3],[1,2]]
print('df1:')
print(df1)
print('df2:')
print(df2)
```

but the outcome is the following. There are unexpected Nan.

```
df1:
      0     1          2     3
0  Name  Unit  Attribute  Date
1     a     F          1   NaN
2     b     G          2   NaN
3     c     C          3  2016
4     d     D          4  2017
5     e   NaN          5   NaN
df2:
      0     1     2
0  Name  Unit  Date
1     a     F  2019
2     b     G  2020
3     e     H  2021
4     f     I  2022
```

Thanks in advance for whoever helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some cleaning:

```
def clean_df(df):
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df.columns.name = None        
    df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index()

    return df

df1 = clean_df(df1)
df1
   index Name Unit Attribute  Date
0      1    a    A         1  2014
1      2    b    B         2  2015
2      3    c    C         3  2016
3      4    d    D         4  2017
4      5    e    E         5  2018

df2 = clean_df(df2)
df2    
   index Name Unit  Date
0      1    a    F  2019
1      2    b    G  2020
2      3    e    H  2021
3      4    f    I  2022
```

---

Use `merge`, specifying `on=Name`, so the other columns are not considered.

```
cols = ['Name', 'Unit_y', 'Attribute', 'Date_y']
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Name')[cols]\
              .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]).fillna(df1)

df1
  Name Unit Attribute  Date
0    a    F         1  2019
1    b    G         2  2020
2    c    C         3  2016
3    d    D         4  2017
4    e    H         5  2021
```

Comment: @John If you are going to insist and say you get the wrong answer, that's because of your data, and not my problem. I should note that's the second time you're doing this, and refusing to acknowledge the effort put into answering your questions and the mangled data that comes with it.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I really appreciate your help. It is just a fact that the outcome I see in my notebook, after using df1.T.reset_index().T is without the first row column index of 0,1,2,3, i.e. 'Name', 'Unit', .etc are the result returned as df1.columns.values.

Comment: @John Just skip that step then.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I have marked your answer as answering my question

Comment: @John Glad to help. What about the other one?

Comment: I closed the other question

Answer (score 1):

Another method with merge and drop duplicates based on transposed dataframe and ffill i.e

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2,on=[0],how='outer').T.set_index(0).sort_index()
        .ffill().reset_index().drop_duplicates(0,keep='last').T.dropna()
```

```
           0     2     3     5
0  Attribute  Date  Name  Unit
1          1  2019     a     F
2          2  2020     b     G
3          3  2016     c     C
4          4  2017     d     D
5          5  2021     e     H
```

Explanation

```
df1.merge(df2,on=[0],how='outer').T.set_index(0).sort_index()
```

Transposed dataframe  will give the dataframe such that we can apply ffill to fill the nan values

```
            1     2     3     4     5     6
0                                            
Attribute     1     2     3     4     5   NaN
Date       2014  2015  2016  2017  2018   NaN
Date       2019  2020   NaN   NaN  2021  2022
Name          a     b     c     d     e     f
Unit          A     B     C     D     E   NaN
Unit          F     G   NaN   NaN     H     I
```

```
.ffill().reset_index().drop_duplicates(0,keep='last')
```

This will fill the nan values with previous rows data and reset_index with drop duplicates of subset 0 and keep the last will keep the completely filled row.

```
         0     1     2     3     4     5     6
0  Attribute     1     2     3     4     5   NaN
2       Date  2019  2020  2016  2017  2021  2022
3       Name     a     b     c     d     e     f
5       Unit     F     G     C     D     H     I
```

```
.T.dropna()
```

This will rotate the dataframe remove rows with nan values resulting in desired output .

Answer (score 0):

I also figured out that below code does what I want and is much faster than two for loops.

```
df1.loc[[1,2,5],[1,3]] = df2.loc[[1,2,3],[1,2]].values
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 answer**: use [DataFrame.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) like this

```py
_df1 = df1.set_index("Name")
_df2 = df2.set_index("Name")
_df1.update(_df2)
updated_df1 = _df1.reset_index()
```